# how to create a container as (a horizontal rectangle) that is curved to the inside from the top side in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

what I am trying to achieve is what is shown in the first image :

[image]

**what I have tried**

```dart
Container(
          width: Get.width,
          height: Get.height * 0.6,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
                top: Radius.elliptical(
                    Get.width , 50)

            ),
          ),
          ),
```

The output out of my code:

[image]

Comment: you may need using Stack/ClipRect or shapeBorder

Comment: try bottom not top --> bottom: Radius.elliptical(300 , x)  [ increase x value as u want]